# Packaged/include text file or other than .ts file in lib folder after yarn build of typescript project using .projenrc.js

Tags: typescript, npm, nodes, tsconfig

I created typescript project using projen (Refer Link : https://github.com/projen/projen)

```
mkdir my-project
git init
npx projen new typescript
```

I have created two files as **sample.txt** & **sample.js**, and
index.ts is a default file created with folder structure. Folder structure created is & lib folder outcome after yarn build :

[image]

If I do yarn build then only .ts file/files getting packaged under lib folder, But I want to include/packaged **.txt & .js** file also
what configuration I will have to mention inside .projenrc.js.
I tried below:

```
tsconfig: {
    include: [
      'src/*.txt',
      'src/*.js',
      'src/**/*.txt',
      'src/**/*.js',
    ],
    compilerOptions: {
      noUnusedLocals: false, // added this so can iterate through builds without errors for variables that have not been used yet.
      noUnusedParameters: false,
    },
  },
```

But no luck.
Any help on this really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using ts config alone, the .txt files will not be moved. You can set ts config with allowJs: true to get the js files bundled.

For the .txt files (or other file types) use a script to copy those files. Something that may be useful is to use copyfiles package:

[copyfiles npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copyfiles)

Tools like nx (https://nx.dev/) provide functionality that help with copying assets, I'm sure other build systems do as well.